# How use Serilog email with asp.net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

In my asp.net core 2.1 project want send mail on error event.
I have an error controller that catch global error and log them with ILogger

Now in main method of Program.cs i do what documentation suggest
but mail is not sent!
Sink works if i move code in ErrorController but i think is bad way

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         var emailInfo = new EmailConnectionInfo
         {
             FromEmail = "xxx",
             ToEmail = "xxxx;",
             MailServer = "smtp.gmail.com",
             EmailSubject = "Error "
        };

         using (var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .MinimumLevel.Error()
                 .WriteTo.Email(emailInfo,
                     outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}\t{Level:u3}\t{SourceContext}\t{Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger()
              )
        {
            logger.Error("Error occured (test)...");
            //CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); or here...
        }

        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

The email with test is sent but not when error of application occurs

I use Logger of microsoft extension in my ErrorController

```
public ErrorController(ILogger<ErrorController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
```

then in a method of errorcontroller i call logger.LogError(exception);

```
       var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        logger.LogError(feature.Error);
```

Comment: I suspect the real question is how to integrate Serilog and ASP.NET Core logging. The code posted here doesn't use Serilog to log anything. Any logging calls eg in controllers will use ASP.NET Core's default logging configuration

Comment: So how i have to set email sink in my application? Im a bit confused

Comment: Nice spotting @PanagiotisKanavos ... OP, you'll still need to actually hook up Serilog and ASP.NET Core to work together. The README examples in https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore covers all of this.

Comment: tks is good link i ignored. But is for netcore 2.2 is with process mode? is it right for netcore 2.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not telling the application to use SeriLog. 
Try following code.

```
using (var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
         .MinimumLevel.Error()
         .WriteTo.Email(emailInfo,
             outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}\t{Level:u3}\t{SourceContext}\t{Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
        .CreateLogger())
{
    logger.Error("Error occured (test)...");
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
         .UseSerilog(logger)
         .Build().Run();
}
```

Personally, I'm creating my logger instance in the Startup.Configure method, using the static Log.Logger property. But the above should work as well.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(this.Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
        ...
    }
```

I'm not very sure how well the default implementation works with SeriLog. You may need to remove all the logging settings from your `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: tks a lot. It works well: so i can remove the log in errorcontroller and use program.cs. Tks again man. have nice day

Comment: Only strange thing is that i recive two log. For example i create custom error as CustomerNotFoundException and it is saved on txt,database and write in email two times

Answer (score 0):

The `using` block in your code tears down Serilog before the application starts up.

Try running the app inside the block:

```
    using (var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .MinimumLevel.Error()
             .WriteTo.Email(emailInfo,
                 outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}\t{Level:u3}\t{SourceContext}\t{Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger())
    {
        logger.Error("Error occured (test)...");
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

Comment: I try and application still works but no mail sent. Tks for help

Comment: However in develpoment mode i see message in debugconsole: Sending batch of 2 logs

Comment: @herosuper you didn't post any code that *uses* the logger. The messages you see come from ASP.NET Core's logging, not Serilog.

Comment: i use ILogger<ErrorController> in my ErrorController to run custom exception and if i write code above in that controller the email is sent but im not sure is correct approach